# How to call java file from php server

Tags: java, php, android

I am working on a project which can solve optimization problems.I have written the whole application in java for desktop use, Now I want to convert it for android mobiles. So How can I call java files from php server to process the result and get back the result. Or I should completely implemented it in android locally.

Comment: Is this question about the choise between local or remote computation? Or is it about running an external program from PHP?

Answer (score -1):

I sudgest you to "rewrite" the code for android, even more considering that android applications are usually written in Java (even if you can speed them up using NDK in C/C++), so its porting should be straight forward.

For the sake of completeness, you can run external programs and retrive their result from PHP with the **exec** function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Hope I answered your question.